# sequence-rings and category

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a problem with exact sequences:
Prove that, there exist an exact sequence
$0 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \longrightarrow 0$
And an exact sequence
$... \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4 \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4 \longrightarrow …$
Is that anyway  to solve this problem or we have to give an direct homomorphism?

Comment: You have to look for specific homomorphisms, yes. Very easy.

Comment: Can you give me sepcofic homorphism?